# Tabs (with fragments) within Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-nested-fragment

I created the tabs by following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcnT-3F-9JA but in this tutorial the tabs are within an activity where as I need them within fragments something like nested fragments.
And for the fragment I have added the code in `onCreateView` I'm getting an error while trying to create an instance of `TrainSearchFragmentAdapter` which is another class that extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

This is my main activity which is a nav drawer activity
[Screenshot of Nav Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLVGz.png)

This is the fragment that opens on clicking a nav option [Screenshot of the fragment with tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZutT.png)

Here is my code for the parent fragment :

```
public class TrainSearchFragment
        extends Fragment implements
        TrainSearchTrainByNoFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        TrainSearchSeatAvailabilityFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        TrainSearchRouteFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    public TrainSearchFragment() {
    }
//...
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_train_search, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_train_search_tablayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Train By No."));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Seat Availability"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Route"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_train_search_viewpager);
        final TrainSearchFragmentAdapter trainSearchFragmentAdapter = new TrainSearchFragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(trainSearchFragmentAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                //getItem
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
//...
}
```

I have also tried using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` on internet in multiple places I found the use of `getSupportFragmentManager()` but I found its depreciated now.

Here is my code for the Adapter fragment :

```
public class TrainSearchFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int mNoOfTabs;
    public TrainSearchFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNoOfTabs = 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                TrainSearchTrainByNoFragment trainSearchTrainByNoFragment = new TrainSearchTrainByNoFragment();
                return trainSearchTrainByNoFragment;
            case 1:
                TrainSearchSeatAvailabilityFragment trainSearchSeatAvailabilityFragment = new TrainSearchSeatAvailabilityFragment();
                return trainSearchSeatAvailabilityFragment;
            case 3:
                TrainSearchRouteFragment trainSearchRouteFragment = new TrainSearchRouteFragment();
                return trainSearchRouteFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNoOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `getSupportFragmentManager()` ?

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan `getSupportFragmentManager()` shows error (red) in Android Studio on Internet it says this method is no longer supported